# Kits not found with Debian

Tags: debian, qt-creator

I'm tring to develop software with Qt creator 4.4.1, in Debian 9.2. When I try to create a new project, Qt creator does not find any kit. When I go in options, it seems I cannot choose anything.

In the past, I have worked a lot in Qt creator under win64, without problems. But now, in Debian, I've some problems and I need your help.

Comment: Have you installed qt?

Comment: Yes, I've installed Qt, and it is just updated.

Comment: You could indicate the steps you took to install qt.

Comment: I useed the " sudo apt-get install build-essential "

Comment: install this packages: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/qt5-default: `qtbase5-dev-tools`, `qt5-qmake`, `qtbase5-dev`.

Comment: I've already installed it. Other advices?

Comment: "When I go in options, it seems I cannot choose anything" Where do you go in the options. To be able to assign a Qt to a kit, you have to register a Qt version in the Build & Run > Qt Versions tab and press Apply.

Comment: Solved: qmake points to qchooser. Manually set qchooser to qt version 5. Manually set path of qmake. Install cmake (it was not installed).

Answer (score 0):

`apt install qtcreator` worked for me.